# Use adb with Atrix 2 running Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I've had no problem getting adb to work with my LG G3 and Nexus 7 2, but it won't recognize my Atrix 2 running ICS.  I've gotten the latest Motorola drivers,
connected in mass storage, media, and camera modes, rebooted my Windows 7 machine with the phone connected/not connected with debugging on/off, even did a factory reset.  adb still doesn't see it as an Android device (and neither does Windows 7 Device Manager).    Any ideas?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this [Adb driver installer](http://adbdriver.com/).

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this (again), but no luck.  This installer looks for devices, and it didn't see my Atrix 2.  Not surprising because Windows Device Manager doesn't see it.  It did see my LG G3 when I connected it, but adb is already working with that phone.

Comment: Is there a chance that problem come from the Atrix or the cable? Have you try to reset your adb using adb kill-server and adb start-sever?

Comment: I have no idea where the original Atrix cable is from 4+ years ago, but it works fine when connected in Mass Storage, Media device, or Camera modes.  I've restarted the server many times.  I'm pretty sure it's SOMETHING in the Atrix 2 because everything except debugging works fine over the cable, and the cable works fine when using adb with other Android devices.  Somebody said they got this problem after upgrading 2.3 to 4.0.4.  I've thought about trying to go back to a 2.3 factory image, but even if that's possible it would probably require a working USB debug connection.

Comment: We need the computer to recognize that there's a device in Device Manager even the driver is not recognized. You should test it with another computer which haven't installed the driver to see where the problem comes from.

Comment: Well, my wife's old Windows Vista machine recognized the device, I installed the driver, and Device Manager shows an Android phone with the ADB device interface installed.  Still not sure why my Windows 7 machine doesn't see it.

Comment: Glad to know that, so, you should uninstall the driver on your windows 7 machine and reinstall it. Hope that will work.

Comment: Removed and reinstalled Motorola drivers AGAIN.  it worked.  Device Manager, AdbDriverInstaller, adb, and Android Studio now all see the device and it works.  Thanks.